# Can't open items from the top panel any more

Tags: bug, ios-app

Just updated the iOS app, and now if I click one of the items on the top (horizontally scrolling) panel, the item dims, as if it is waiting for the data to display, but it never opens. I can click other items, and they dim, but nothing ever opens.

The app remains otherwise responsive at all times. This worked fine in the previous version I had.

- App Version: 1.6.0.10
- Device: iPad 4 (Wi-Fi)
- OS Version: Version 9.3.5 (Build 13G36)

Comment: Do you mean this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/285194/307988

Comment: @Cai yup, that's the one. Never thought of calling them "hot questions," which is probably why I could find anything when I searched. Thanks